# C# Project File cannot be loaded

Tags: c#, filesystems, clickonce

I was trying to publish my application and I was getting an error that the file path name exceeded the maximum character length.  So I went and changed the name of the my solution and the name of the its two projects.  I built solution again, then exited and reloaded VS.  When I opened solution, the project I renamed now has an exclamation point on it and in parenthesis[image] it says, "Load Failed".  What have I done?

Comment: What does the error list say?

Comment: You need to then select the project with the warning, browse to it again from the properties view and finally right click on it and "Reload". This has to be a duplicate...

Comment: hmm...I can't change the path of the file from the properties window - it is greyed out.